# How to bind the text of an anchor tag with resources?

Tags: asp.net, binding

the following tag did not work.

```
<a href="http://google.com"><%$ Resources:Resource, googleTitle %></a>
```

Any idea !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `HyperLink` instead because `$` works with asp.net server controls perfectly.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="http://google.com"
    Text='<%$ Resources:Resource, googleTitle %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Otherwise simply use asp.net code having `=` symbol.

```
<a href="http://google.com"><%= Resources.Resource.googleTitle %></a>
```